# PHP - variable using substr() cant be extended

Tags: php, substring, substr

I'm creating an account-system. The user gives his first name & last name. I create a record in my database with the first letter of their first name and their full last name.

To get their first letter I do this in my code:

```
$first_letter = substr($voornaam, 0, 1);
echo "Eerste letter-variabele: ";
var_dump($first_letter);
echo "<br/>";

$gebruiker = $first_letter;
echo "overgezet in gebruiker-variabele: ";
var_dump($gebruiker);
echo "<br/>";
```

the var_dumps return exactly what I want, a string containing the first letter of given first name.

To create the 2nd part of the username I just do:

```
$gebruiker += $achternaam;
echo "+achternaam: ";
var_dump($gebruiker);
echo "<br/>";
```

This returns an int(0) (probably boolean saying false). I have searched and found nothing. I assume this has something to do with sub_str() still functioning (?) Could someone please show me the proper way to solve this problem (Object-Oriented would be welcome).

Comment: + is for numbers, "." is for string concatenation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.=` in stead of `+=` and it will work.

`+` adds up (as in Math) ... and `.` is used for concatenation.

Now make your own huiswerk... ;)

Comment: oooh bedankt, ik ben de laatste tijd teveel bezig geweest met c++ vandaar de fout. Jammer genoeg is dit geen huiswerk maar een project voor een echte klant :D

Comment: I would suggest you translate your comment. But reading the contents, I'd again suggest you don't :D

Comment: Assuming by your name, nl-x, you sure know what i've said ;)

Comment: Hope that client of yours doesn't know about stackoverflow or he might reconsider =P

Comment: Haha, the clients come through our school. We have a business hosted by our IT-department of school which takes on projects from out-side school companies. This makes us learn more effectively as it feels that we're really working in a company ourselves. + we earn a little cash ( not much, as we don't deliver high quality work ) which we can buy stuff for our department :)